# Is it possible to use data from an HTML attribute with url() in a CSS content property?

Tags: html, css

I can place some additional content via CSS to my HTML code:

HTML:

```
<a href="test.html" data-tooltip="/content.svg">
```

CSS:

```
[data-tooltip]::after {
  content: url(/content.svg);
}
```

Is there a way, to get the URL from the HTML code? Something like this:

```
  content: url(attr(data-tooltip));
```

I would like to show a separate tooltip for each link with a description of the linked page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content - it’s possible without url() for the target; see attr(x). The original question species url(), for which I’m unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access attributes from other elements, but you can maybe set an HTML variable in the parent element and then use it in your css in the pseudo elements

```css
    a.test::after { 
        content: var(--content);
    }
```

```html
<a class="test" href="test.html" style="--content: url(./content.png);">
test
</a>
```